# "Webapps" or "web-apps" or "web apps"?

Tags: discussion

What is the preferred usage?

I have been finding myself alternating between `web apps` and `webapps`, however I think `webapps` might be better - after all, the AP Stylebook recently changed `web site` to `website`, so I expect the same movement for `web apps` -> `webapps`.

And how should this be worked out, or do we even need a standard?

For example, it could just be one answer for each, and then you vote up your preferred term, but I think it would be better with reasonings being voted on - see mine below.

Answer (score 6):

Web apps - because currently, it is more popular in terms of search usage.

See the Google Trends comparison:

[image: Google Trends]

It is interesting to see from the Trends page http://www.google.com/trends?q=web+apps,+web-apps,+webapps,+web+applications&ctab=0&geo=all&date=all&sort=2 that **'web apps' is more popular in the USA**, and that 'web applications' is more popular in countries such as India, Pakistan and the Philippines - probably indicative of high developer concentrations (eg you would search web application development).

Also - **that is what Microsoft used** in their naming of 'Office Web Apps'.

Comment: [Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore) description: An open marketplace for **web apps**

Comment: your image (hosted on Pict!) has disappeared because your account expired; perhaps you may wish to remove or replace it.

Answer (score -1):

Webapps - for the reason discussed above about the AP Stylebook moving from web site to website, and it makes sense to use webapps so that when that is the commonly used term, the questions and answers on this site will be more relevant to search engines and easier to find.